# Issue with combining multiple lookahead regex in Python

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to get a regex for the following conditions:

Validate User ID with following conditions:

1. It must contain at least 2 uppercase English alphabet characters.
2. It must contain at least 3 digits
3. It should only contain alphanumeric characters
4. No character should repeat.
5. There must be exactly 10 characters in a valid UID.

**The Regex which works when I put check separately but not combined:**

```
^(?=[a-zA-Z0-9]{10}$).*?(?=[A-Z][^A-Z]*?[A-Z]).*?(?=\d\D*?\d\D*?\d).*
```

Could someone please clarify why this is not working?

**Working when put each condition separate:**

a. `re.findall(r'^(?=[a-zA-Z0-9]{10}$)', inp)`

b. `re.findall(r'(?=[A-Z][^A-Z]*?[A-Z])', inp)` ...

Comment: What would be the right output for __AT934j3Cn8__? That one should be fine. However, try re.compile(r'^(?=[a-zA-Z0-9]{10}$)|(?=[A-Z][^A-Z]?[A-Z])|(?=\d\D?\d\D*?\d).*')

Comment: *No character should repeat.* In the entire string or just next to each other?

Comment: That's not a good problem to solve with regular expressions. When checking one specific character, your program should "remember" too many things ("was this char already used? Do I already have another uppercase letter?" etc.) Regular expressions are not very good at checking previous occurrences of values. I would try another approach (for example, manually counting the characters into dictionaries.)

Comment: @brandizzi I am sorry that you are not fan of regex or you didn't liked my approach, My question is not to solve the problem, instead, try to understand why my lookahead's combined doesn't work and the other one with individual lookahead worked

Comment: Oh, mind you, I like regex, but not much in this case ;) Could you show us which strings are not being matched by your regular expression? It could help us to understand what is going on.

Comment: Please find the sample where combined lookahead fails -
 https://regex101.com/r/cbBLsG/1

Answer (score 1):

you can use the regex

```
(?!.*(.).*\1)(?=.*[A-Z].*[A-Z])(?=.*\d.*\d.*\d)[a-zA-Z0-9]{10}
```

see the [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/eRZqub/1).

(?!.*(.).*\1) ensures that no character is repeated 
(?=.*[A-Z].*[A-Z]) ensures that at least 2 uppercase char are present 
(?=.*\d.*\d.*\d) ensures that atleast 3 digits are present 
[a-zA-Z0-9]{10} matches 10 alphanumeric characters

Comment: Thanks for the the code for something I have learned. But, could you please explain what is the flaw in my approach with multiple lookahead combined (as posted in my original question)?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regex as you describe:

```
/(?=(?:.*[A-Z].*){2,})(?=(?:.*\d.*){3,})(?!=(.).*\1)(^[a-zA-Z0-9]{10}$)/
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4Md0O7/1/)

Comment: Thanks @dawg. I think I should be more specific to my question, My question is not to solve the problem, instead, try to understand why my lookahead's combined doesn't work and the other one with individual lookahead worked

Comment: There is a link (under 'Demo') that takes you to an interactive regex site. Look at a working regex and then debug the one that you are trying to understand. Edit your question if you are getting answers different that what your are looking for.